# Hide password from all MongoDB queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've the following schema. Its of a user and the document has several fields. What i need is that once the user signups the passwords becomes hidden, that whichever db queries (e.g. find,update etc) i run password always remains hidden.

I know about the exclusion/making password:0 in mongo queries, e.g. as of now I am excluding the password using following approach:

```
User.find({} , {password: 0}).populate('favoriteListings').populate('myListings').populate('profilePicture').limit(size).skip(itemsToSkip)
      .exec(function (err, result) { // LIMIT THE RESULT TO 5 DOCUMENTS PER QUERY
        if (err) return next(err)
        return res.json(result)
      })
```

i.e I am excluding password from the json result individually at all queries. What i need is to make something like password:{hidden:true} and whenever i do any query password is not returned.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema; // creating schema
var Listing = require('../listing/listingModel');
var Media = require('../media/mediaModel');

var UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: {type: String,default: null}, // EMAIL ID AND PASSWORD ARE TO BE KEPT ON MAIN OF SCHEMA
  password: {type: String,default: null},

  personal: { // personal information
    firstName: {type: String,default: null},
    lastName: {type: String,default: null},
    dateOfBirth: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    description: {type: String,default: null},
    contactNo: {type: String,default: '0000-0000-0000'},
    gender: {
      male: {type: Boolean,default: true},
      female: {type: Boolean,default: false}
    }

  },

  preferences: {
    budget: {type: Number,default: 0},
    moveInDate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    profileViewable: {type: Boolean,default: true}
  },

  background: { // Has an array of work experiences
    workExperience: [{ // can have multiple experiences so it is an array
      employer: {type: String,default: null},
      position: {type: String,default: null},
      descrpiton: {type: String,default: null},
      startDate: {type: Date,default: Date.now},
      endDate: {type: Date,default: Date.now}
    }]
  },

  profilePicture: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Media' },
  favoriteListings: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Listing' }],
  myListings: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Listing' }],
  status: {type: Boolean,default: true} // STATUS OF ENTRY, BY DEFAULT ACTIVE=TRUE
},
  {
    // MAKING VIRTUALS TRUE
    toObject: {
      virtuals: true
    },
    toJSON: {
      virtuals: true
    },

    timestamps: true, // FOR createdAt and updatedAt
    versionKey: false,
    id: false // because toObject virtuals true creates another id field in addition to _id so making it false
  }

)

UserSchema
  .virtual('fullName')
  .get(function () {
    // console.log(this.createdAt)
    if (this.firstName != null && this.lastName != null) {return this.name.firstName + ' ' + this.name.lastName}
    else
      return null
  })

var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)

module.exports = User
```

Following is the code for login user

```
User.findOne({
  email: req.body.email
}).select('+hash +salt').exec( function (err, validadmin) {
  if (err) return next(err)

  if (!validadmin) {
    res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. User not found.' })
  } else if (validadmin) {
    var decryptedPassword = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(validadmin.password, myPasswordKey) // DECRYPTING PASSWORD
    // OBTAINED FROM DB TO MATCH WITH PASSWORD GIVEN BY USER
    decryptedPassword = decryptedPassword.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)
    console.log(decryptedPassword)
    console.log(req.body.password)
    // check if password matches
    if (decryptedPassword != req.body.password) {
      return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.' })
    } else {
      // CREATES TOKEN UPON SUCCESSFUL LOGIN
      var token = jwt.sign(validadmin, app.get('superSecret'), {
        expiresIn: 24 * 60 * 60
      })

      // LOGIN SUCCESSFUL
      return res.json({
        success: true,
        message: 'LOGIN SUCCESSFUL!',
        token: token
      })
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Add:

```
select: false
```

to the password property in your User model.

```
password: {type: String,default: null,select:false}
```

btw you should be encrypting your password before saving it to the database!

Comment: In this case the password gets hidden from query results. But when I do signin using password and email following error comes TypeError: cannot read property "salt" of undefined. Btw i'm using jwt for password encryption

Comment: In your login strategy you have to retrieve an user for the database and check it against the user that is trying to login right? In the query that is searching for an user add .select('+hash +salt') after the find method.

Comment: If you don't want to get the hash and salt when you're for example querying your database to display the user profile, you can also do the following
`User.find(id)..select('-hash -salt')`
I think that would work

Comment: used select(-hash -salt) still no use, same old error

Comment: Remove the select: false property from your model and use .select('-hash -salt') in all the routes you want to query for your user information

Comment: Yeah that prevents the error, but how to resolve the password issue

Comment: @AliRazaSherazi use `.select("+password")` to include the `select:false` field.

Answer (score 0):

```
const { password,  ...others } = user._doc;
```

`user` is the main object you want to remove password

then send it like this:

```
res.status(200).json(others);
```

Simple!!! Good luck